# iframe pdf not displaying correctly on mobile device

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I have an app that is a webview displaying a webpage. Within the page I display a pdf document using the following:

```
<iframe id="pdfReport" class="pdfFrame"></iframe>
```

When the page loads the pdf at a given path is displayed in the iframe.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var pdfDoc = pathToPdf
    document.getElementById('pdfReport').src = pdfDoc;
});
```

If viewed using a browser on PC or laptop the display is fine - filename, number of page etc:

[image]

If viewed using an iPad (Chrome or Safari) it only displays page 1 with scrolling, no frame, filename, number of page etc:

[image]

How do I get the pdf to display correctly in the device?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google Doc Viewer?

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var pdfDoc = "https://www.yourpdf.com/";
    var pathToPdf =  "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + pdfDoc + "&embedded=true";
    var pdfDoc = pathToPdf
    document.getElementById('pdfReport').src = pdfDoc;
});
```

Comment: Yes I could use that but wanted to avoid it if possible. I was hoping for an alternative.

Comment: I don't believe there is a good alternative to view PDFs on mobile. If it's a major requirement you could try a library like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ - Or just embed the PDF as a download on mobile.